# Installing airflow apache hive provider with dockerfile, getting GCC permission denied

Tags: docker, gcc, dockerfile, airflow

So, I'm running this dockerfile to build my image:

FROM apache/airflow:2.4.2
RUN pip install gspread
RUN pip install oauth2client
RUN pip install PyHive
RUN pip install python-dev-tools
RUN pip install essentials
RUN pip install apache-airflow-providers-apache-hive

When it gets to the last one, I get an error saying that it could not finish because:
GCC permssion denied.

I have admin rights, if I execute directly like sudo pip install apache-airflow-providers-apache-hive and I insert my password, I can install the module, however, since I need to do it on a dockerfile, I don't know what to do.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you switch to root before doing the `pip install` via `USER root`?

Comment: It doesn't allow me to execute. It says "You are running pip as root. Please use 'airflow' user to run pip!"